# How to test .then(function in Unit Testing AgularJS with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, controller, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am not clear how to use SpyOn in Unit Testing...

I have the following controller

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('otpConfigureDatasets').controller('otpActivityCardController', otpActivityCardController);

    otpActivityCardController.$inject = ['$location', '$state', 'otpWebMapApp', 'otpWMDeltaTracker', 'otpWMStateCache', '$scope', '$timeout', 'otpActivityCardService', 'otpControlCenterData'];

    function otpActivityCardController($location, $state, otpWebMapApp, otpWMDeltaTracker, otpWMStateCache, $scope, $timeout, otpActivityCardService, otpControlCenterData) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.cards = [];

        otpActivityCardService.getActivityCards().then(function (resolve) {
            vm.cards = resolve;
        });

        //.....Some code ....

})();
```

I need to test the GetActivityCards().then(function ...

I tried test it using the code below

```
'use strict';

describe('Test controller (activityCard) in Page MyDatasets', function() {

var MainCtrl, $state, scope, otpWebMapApp, otpWMDeltaTracker, otpWMStateCache, otpActivityCardService, otpControlCenterData;
var card;

beforeEach(function() {
    module('otpConfigureDatasets');
});

 beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _$state_, _otpWebMapApp_, _otpWMDeltaTracker_, _otpWMStateCache_, _otpActivityCardService_, _otpControlCenterData_) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    scope.$parent = { $parent: { menuParentGroupClick: function menuParentGroupClick() { } } };
    MainCtrl = $controller('otpActivityCardController', {
        $scope: scope
    });
    otpWebMapApp = _otpWebMapApp_;
    otpWMDeltaTracker = _otpWMDeltaTracker_;
    otpWMStateCache = _otpWMStateCache_;
    otpActivityCardService = _otpActivityCardService_;
    otpControlCenterData = otpControlCenterData;
}));

it('Test Function', function() {

    spyOn(otpActivityCardService, 'getActivityCards');

    expect(otpActivityCardService.getActivityCards).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

});
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Expected spy getActivityCards to have been called.
Error: Expected spy getActivityCards to have been called.
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You created a spy to the "getActivityCards" function, but you didn't call it in your test (unless you hid this line of code from the example).

When you create a Jasmine Spy to a function, you are only "watching" this function, you can check if it was called, you can mock the return values of it, you can check the parameters of a call to it, i.e, you can check a lot of things about the call history of the function, but you still need to explicity make a call to the function (or to a function in your controller that calls the spied function from it).

So you are spying the Service, and you are testing the Controller, your test should look something like:

```
it('Test Function', function() {

    spyOn(otpActivityCardService, 'getActivityCards');

    otpActivityCardService.getActivityCards();

    expect(otpActivityCardService.getActivityCards).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

On a side note, to be more testable, your controller should encapsulate your service call in a function in your controller, like:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('otpConfigureDatasets').controller('otpActivityCardController', otpActivityCardController);

    otpActivityCardController.$inject = ['$location', '$state', 'otpWebMapApp', 'otpWMDeltaTracker', 'otpWMStateCache', '$scope', '$timeout', 'otpActivityCardService', 'otpControlCenterData'];

    function otpActivityCardController($location, $state, otpWebMapApp, otpWMDeltaTracker, otpWMStateCache, $scope, $timeout, otpActivityCardService, otpControlCenterData) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.cards = [];

        vm.getCards = function () {
            otpActivityCardService.getActivityCards().then(function (resolve) {
                vm.cards = resolve;
            });
        }
        vm.getCards();

        //.....Some code ....

})();
```

So you could create a test that really tested a function in your controller (because the way you are describing your test case, it really should be a Service test only)

```
it('Better test case', function() {

    spyOn(otpActivityCardService, 'getActivityCards');

    MainCtrl.getCards();

    expect(otpActivityCardService.getActivityCards).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```